# Questions about AdvOR on topic?

Tags: discussion

Should we accept questions about [AdvOR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/), the "Advanced" Onion Router?

This came recently up, see [Sharing Tor network via Wi-Fi for Circumvention](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/706/sharing-)tor-network-via-wi-fi).

- Absence in the Tor community.
- No Linux support.
- The [Nick Mathewson's (Tor's Chief Architect) analysis](http://archives.seul.org/or/talk/Oct-2010/msg00026.html) and recommends against.

Answer (score 2):

It's software that uses the Tor network, and is a legitimate fork of the codebase. I don't see a problem with it being on topic.

There could be an issue with actually getting answers to questions asked about it, as it likely has a smaller community than the 'official' Tor client, but I don't think that's necessarily a problem with them being on topic or not.